# Convex hull of piece-wise linear functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, polynomials, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $K>1$ be a positive integer. Consider a function class $$\mathcal{F}_K:=\Big\{\max_{1\leq k\leq K} a_k^\top x + b_k:\ ||a_k||\leq 1, |b_k|\leq 1, \forall 1\leq k\leq K \Big\}$$ on some compact region. Set $-\mathcal{F}_K:=\{-f:f\in\mathcal{F}_K\}$. What is the convex hull of $\mathcal{F}_K\cup\{-\mathcal{F}_K\}$?

Comment: Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a convex cone, the convex hull is the same set as $\mathcal{F}-\mathcal{F}$

Comment: Isn't the convex hull of $\mathcal{F}$ the set of all convex functions?

Comment: @PietroMajer Why is $\mathcal{F}$ convex? The number of pieces is fixed as $K$.

Comment: @Dirk Is it obvious? Here the number of pieces is fixed.

Comment: But taking the convex hull should allow at least countably many kinks. Or are these $a_k$'s and $b_k$'s fixed?

Comment: @Dirk I modified the problem statement a bit. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Err, that's quite a different problem now... Anyway, I still think that the convex hull makes the $K$ superfluous.

Comment: @Dirk taking the convex hull produces piece-wise affine functions, each with finitely many pieces, though with possibly any number of pieces.

Comment: @PietroMajer Doh, you're right, of course.